SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D' when deploying with Flask
For now, everything works as I expect it to be. But I am told it is never a good idea to ignore a SyntaxWarning, especially because it will become a SyntaxError soon, so here is my problem:
I wrote a simple app that I launch with Flask:
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string 
import re

Somewhere in my script, I wrote to make sure the input is numeric-only:
cleaned_input = re.sub(r'\D', '', user_input)

Now, I know you have to use the 'r' prefix when using backslash \.
In a simple script, I get what I expect without a SyntaxWarning:
import re

string = "444.333.222"

cleaned_string = re.sub(r'\D', '', string)

print(cleaned_string)

>>> 444333222

However, when I test my app locally, the following message is returned in my Terminal:
(venv) user@my_laptop Webtool % "directory/" "directory/Webtool/app.py"
directory/Webtool/app.py:9: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D'
  form_template = '''
  * Serving Flask app 'app'  
  * Debug mode: on
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
directory/Webtool/app.py:9: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\D'
  form_template = '''
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: ***-***-***

Changing "" to '' or vice versa does not seem to make a difference nor does using \\D. Because there is no problem in the simple script, my assumption is that it has to do with the Flask deployment.
Again, my app works as expected but I don't think it is a good idea to ignore the warning. Any ideas?
